# redirecting complete make output to a file

Tags: bash, unix, console, makefile, io-redirection

I want to redirect complete make output to a file.

I tried redirecting the stdout and stderr with the following command:

```
make >aks_file.txt 2>&1 &
```

But that is not redirecting the EXACT complete output which is otherwise generated by issuing just make (some lines are missing)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Some programs (either `make` or what `make` invokes) can detect whether their output streams are attached to the console or file and change their behavior (what they output) accordingly. To be more specific, more details on what output exactly is missing and by what program it is being generated when ran without redirection is needed.